# Unexpected results from ST_Intersects(LINESTRING, POLYGON)

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am having a bit of difficultly getting accurate results from a table of mine that contains geometric data. I'm currently using PostGIS 2.1.3, PostgreSQL 9.3.4 and GEOS 3.3.8, though I've also reproduced the issue on early versions.

I have a table, Track, which maintains a LINESTRING summarizing its various locations through time. I need to build the line in real time. When a new Track is added, I create a line from 2 points, then subsequently update the line when new information becomes available. To handle that, I've been using the ST_AddPoint function. I have noticed that I don't get all of the expected tracks when I issue an ST_Intersects query. Lastly, I have tried the same approach with ST_MakeLine which does work.

I have managed to boil the issue down to a very simple test case which shows the failure. I start with a clean spatially enabled database ( postgis.sql and spatial_ref_sys.sql loaded ) .

```
create table track
(
    id serial
);

select AddGeometryColumn('track', 'track_region', 0, 'LINESTRING', 2);

create index trk_rgn_idx on track using GIST ( track_region  );

insert into track (track_region) values(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(600.6 129.877, 585.785 170.165 )'));

update track set track_region = ST_AddPoint( track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(572.741 211.551)'));
update track set track_region = ST_AddPoint( track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(558.694 251.969)'));
update track set track_region = ST_AddPoint( track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(544.725 292.666)'));
update track set track_region = ST_AddPoint( track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(531.029 333.661)'));
update track set track_region = ST_AddPoint( track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(518.303 375.281)'));
update track set track_region = ST_AddPoint( track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(506.037 416.302)'));
update track set track_region = ST_AddPoint( track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(492.891 455.689)'));
update track set track_region = ST_AddPoint( track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(480.456 491.382)'));
update track set track_region = ST_AddPoint( track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(469.236 522.899)'));

select id from track where( ST_Intersects(track_region, 'POLYGON((100 400,500 400,500 1200,100 1200,100 400))'));
```

Failed return:

```
 id
----
(0 rows)
```

When I attempt the ST_MakeLine approach, below, I get the expect result.

```
drop table track;

create table track
(
    id serial
);

select AddGeometryColumn('track', 'track_region', 0, 'LINESTRING', 2);

create index trk_rgn_idx on track using GIST ( track_region  );

insert into track (track_region) values(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(600.6 129.877, 585.785 170.165 )'));

update track set track_region = ST_MakeLine( track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(572.741 211.551)'));
update track set track_region = ST_MakeLine( track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(558.694 251.969)'));
update track set track_region = ST_MakeLine( track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(544.725 292.666)'));
update track set track_region = ST_MakeLine( track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(531.029 333.661)'));
update track set track_region = ST_MakeLine( track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(518.303 375.281)'));
update track set track_region = ST_MakeLine( track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(506.037 416.302)'));
update track set track_region = ST_MakeLine( track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(492.891 455.689)'));
update track set track_region = ST_MakeLine( track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(480.456 491.382)'));
update track set track_region = ST_MakeLine( track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(469.236 522.899)'));

select id from track where( ST_Intersects(track_region, 'POLYGON((100 400,500 400,500 1200,100 1200,100 400))'));
```

Which returns the expected.

```
 id
----
  1
(1 row)
```

Can anyone figure what I'm doing wrong? My guess is that it's something with how I'm using ST_AddPoint to create the line because if I just insert the line all at once everything works fine. Also though, if I select the line after it's been added with ST_AddPoint, then use it in a query like so, it works.

```
select ST_Intersects('LINESTRING(600.6 129.877,585.785 170.165,572.741 211.551,558.694 251.969,544.725 292.666,531.029 333.661,518.303 375.281,506.037 416.302,492.891 455.689,480.456 491.382,469.236 522.899)', 'POLYGON((100 400,500 400,500 1200,100 1200,100 400))' );

 id
----
  1
(1 row)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've asked a moderator to move this to **gis.stackexchange.com** (though I accidentally said dba in the flag, sorry to the mods), where this kind of question gets more attention. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: @CraigRinger. I just spent an hour looking at this and Mike T has posted the solution. Give us a chance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Mike T has said about you having hit a [bug](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2845), you can "fix" your query by wrapping the ST_Intersects with ST_MakeValid or by buffering by a tiny amount.

Both

```
select id from track where ST_Intersects(ST_MakeValid(track_region),
   ST_GeomfromText('POLYGON((100 400,500 400,500 1200,100 1200,100 400))'));
```

and

```
 select id from track where ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(track_region,0.0000001),
   ST_GeomfromText('POLYGON((100 400,500 400,500 1200,100 1200,100 400))'));
```

return your intersected id, though the second one is admitedly hacky. If you run ST_IsValid(track_region) you get true, but ST_MakeValid "solves" the query problem anyway, even though the geometry is considered to be valid. ST_Buffer(geom, 0) is a hack for fixing node order, which does not work here without a small buffer, but is a useful thing to know.

As an aside, your query above:

```
select id from track where( ST_Intersects(track_region, 'POLYGON((100 400,500 400,500 1200,100 1200,100 400))'));
```

is invalid, it should be:

```
select id from track where ST_Intersects(track_region, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((100 400,500 400,500 1200,100 1200,100 400))'));
```

Comment: Thanks John, I appreciate the final tip of ST_GeomFromText, I had forgotten that. Interesting that ST_MakeValid 'fixes' the issue. I had read a bit about it from someone else's troubles but didn't think it was relevant in this case. I will use it in conjunction with ST_AddPoint ( I didn't really like using MakeLine over and over. I appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: You are welcome. It actually took me much longer than it should have done to figure this out because I am not used to finding bugs in Postgis (unlike certain other spatially enabled DBs I have worked with, and had better not mention).

Answer (score 3):

You have found a bug with ST_Point, which has been simplified [here as #2845](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2845).

I would consider using a simple method of creating a LineString geometry, rather than repetitively updating the table. [ST_MakeLine](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) has an example using an array of point geometries, which I think is a good start. You can also use [array_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) to help build these point arrays, if you have tables of point geometries.

Comment: I am glad you found that, I was starting to question my sanity. I even exported the line and polygon as shp and looked at them in QGIS, which also returned false for the intersection, for what it is worth.

Comment: I was suspicious about a bug, but typically assume I'm doing something wrong. Thanks for digging out the bug report. I will look into your suggestions, though I don't know if there is any alternative to building the line incrementally. The application is video analysis related. On every frame we are given new information which needs to get recorded. At an given point in time we need to have data consistency and the ability to perform downstream statistical processing. New frame, new data, new point for the line.